# How do I get the index var to work in my for loop?

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, indexing

It is now solved. Thank you all that hepled! :-)

I am new at programming and trying to learn.
Wanted to write a code in Kotlin that creates a list with 10 spaces and then fills them with random numbers.
But in my for loop the index value (myList[i]) is red.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 var myList = listOf<Int>()
 val times = 10

    for (i in myList) {
        val randomNumber = (1..100).random()
        myList[i] = randomNumber
    }
}
```

The end code that works:

```
 var testar = mutableListOf<Int>()

    for (int in 0..10) {
        val randomNumber = (1..100).random()
        val int = randomNumber
        testar.add(int)
    }
```

Comment: first of all, `for (i in myList)` won't do anything. `myList` is empty, there will be no iteration. Secondly, you can't do `myList[i] = whatever` because `myList` is a `List<Int>` which is read-only. You need a mutable list, which you make: `val myList = mutableListOf<Int>()`

Comment: Hi there. You say that something "is red", but can you update your question with the exact error message, and what you think it means? What do you expect variable `i` to be? And have you tried looking through the [for loop documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops)?

Answer (score 1):

1. myList should be mutable as you want to add items to it
2. you need to iterate the 0..times not myList as it's empty
3. you can only access particular index if it's not empty (so in case of myList after the numbers are added)

sample solution:

```kotlin
var myList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val times = 10

for (i in 0..times) {
    val randomNumber = (1..100).random()
    myList.add(randomNumber)
}
println("$myList")
println("${myList[0]}, ${myList[10]}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes it clear. :-)